# Relation between connected subset and clopen subset of a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I've read that for $A$ a connected subset of a metric space $M$ and $C$ a clopen (closed and open) subset of $M$, one could prove that either $A \subset C$ or $A \cap C=\varnothing$ and use it to prove that $\overline{A}$ is a connected subset of $M$.

I don't see how neither of the proofs can be done, I'm guessing I haven't spotted the right idea...

Can you help me please? I'd like to figure this out!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider $A\cap C$ and $A\setminus C$.

Comment: $A\cap C$ is *clopen* in the *connected* space $A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure I see what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, suppose not, then $A\cap C\neq \emptyset$ and $A\setminus C\neq \emptyset$, which are open set in $A$ separates $A$. Then it contradicts $A$ is connected.

For the second one, you can prove if $A$ is connected, $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then $A\cup \{x\}$ is also connected, since if it's not, there are two open sets $G_1,G_2$ separate it. Then $A$ must be inside one of them, say $G_1$ and $x\in G_2$, then it will contradict the fact $x$ be a limit point. And $\bar{A}$ is just $A$ unions all its limit points.

Comment: Does the first part uses the clopenness of $C$? I feel like both sets are empty making $A$ empty... Could you give a little more detail ? I'm sure I completely understand...

Comment: @Yes We need $C$ clopen s.t. $A\cap C,A\setminus C$ are open in $A$.

Comment: Oh sorry, nice, I saw it the wrong way around, thanks a lot! Are you using the first part to prove the second? I don't see why $A$ union $x$ is also connected...

Comment: @Noome I gave more details in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's all bright clear now!! It wasn't all that hard in the end, I was searching for far too complicated solutions!

Comment: @Noome I am glad it helps.